# How do I declare a variable and set the value in a class

Tags: typescript

I think this code should be right. But it's not. Why?

```
export module Menu {
    export class FileHandler {

        var infoDisabled : boolean = false;

        isInfoDisabled() : boolean {
            return infoDisabled;
        }
```

What do I have wrong in this? (I've tried a lot of variations, none worked.)

Comment: You might find this useful - http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Thank you. I've read through that a couple of times. Doesn't mean it's all stuck in my mind yet.

Comment: use `this` keyword to refer variables and methods in your class when you use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick changes... Mark the property private (or public if you like) and access it using this.

```
export class FileHandler {

    private infoDisabled : boolean = false;

    isInfoDisabled() : boolean {
        return this.infoDisabled;
    }
```

Comment: thank you! I keep forgetting I need to explicitly put in this.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. :)

```
export module Menu {
    export class FileHandler {

        infoDisabled : boolean = false;

        isInfoDisabled() : boolean {
            return this.infoDisabled;
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot define variables at the class level, only properties and methods. Accessing infoDisabled requires the 'this' keyword. And you were missing one or two closing braces. :)

Comment: thank you! I keep forgetting I need to explicitly put in this.